# How can I set aria-labelledby using ng-attr-aria-labelledby

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

How can I set aria-label based on a condition?

I have tried

```
ng-attr-aria-labelledby="{{Cntl.label ? 'group-label-Cntl.uniqueId' : ''}}"
```

But it's not coming as expected.
"group-label-" is static & "Cntl.uniqueId" will give a dynamic id for each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are just passing the `uniqueId` property in as a string. Instead you want to refer the actual property like so.

```html
ng-attr-aria-labelledby="{{Cntl.label ? 'group-label-'+Cntl.uniqueId : ''}}"
```